# UIButton not responding to touches - no scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uibutton, touch

[image]

This is my view hierarchy. Send arrow is not responding immediately on the device, it takes multiple touches to trigger the action. But on the simulator, it works perfectly fine. There are no explicit gesture recognisers added in any view, no scroll views and the super view does not delay touch events or anything that I'e noticed in similar questions.

EDIT: Action added through the storyboard. I tried for all touch events and for all of them, the touch is non responsive. Only after a few touches, the action is triggered.

[image]

Here's the view debug hierarchy.

Is there any reason why the touch trigger is blocked here? I'm stymied. Help?!

Comment: how you acheived target action?using code or IBAction

Comment: @RohitKP trigger connections made through the storyboard. Not using code.

Comment: check for control event to be touch up Inside...reconnect the IBAction

Comment: Can you check your view debug hierarchy? I doubt something might be blocking the button or button might be out of the frame of its superview

Comment: look like frame or constraint issue.

Comment: @lalit Kumar, I have checked the frame if the button during run time. I even set a background image for the button to check if the button is fully within the superview. Please elaborate on how I can check if the frame/constraints is still an issue?

Comment: @Arun, I have attached the view hierarchy screenshot for reference.  I did check the frame of the button during runtime, it seems to be alright. What about the frame could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps override the touches of Views.

Use this way to add your Views.

```
       [self.view insertSubview:viewToAdd aboveSubview:mapView_];
```

If You adding Views for XIB then Send you map view to back.

```
        [mapView_ sendSubviewToBack:YourView];
```

Comment: What does sendSubviewToBack: do? Would've it bring the map view to the foreground and infect block my subview?

Comment: I am already inserting the mapview at index 0 to ensure it doesn't overlay on any other views.

Comment: SendSubviewtoback insures that your view doesn't overlap your view. and How does you insert Map in index 0.